# Handling Two hasMany Relationships

Tags: ember.js

What would be the best way to have and object that has two `hasMany` relationships.

Models:

```
App.Gradebook = DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  students: DS.hasMany('student', { async: true }),
  assignments: DS.hasMany('assignment', { async: true })
});
App.Student = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  gradebook: DS.belongsTo('gradebook'),
  grades: DS.hasMany('grade', { async: true })
});
App.Assignment = DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  total: DS.attr('number'),
  gradebook: DS.belongsTo('gradebook'),
  grades: DS.hasMany('grade', { async: true })
});
App.Grade = DS.Model.extend({
  score: DS.attr('number'),
  student: DS.belongsTo('student'),
  assignment: DS.belongsTo('assignment')
});
```

Currently, this is the way I have it setup:

Template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="gradebooks">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    {{#each}}
      <li {{bind-attr class="isActive:active"}}>
        {{#link-to "gradebook" this}}
          {{title}}
        {{/link-to}}
      </li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
  <div class="content">
    {{#if hasGradebooks}}
      {{outlet}}
    {{/if}}
  </div>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="gradebook">
  <h2>{{title}}</h2>
  <table>
    <thead><tr>
      <th>Students</th>
      {{#each assignments}}
        <th>{{title}} ({{total}})</th>
      {{/each}}
    </tr><thead>
    <tbody>
      {{#each student in students}}
        <tr>
          <td>{{student.name}}</td>
          {{#each assignment in assignments}}
            <td>{{student}}{{assignment}}{{getGrade student assignment}}</td>
          {{/each}}
        </tr>
      {{/each}}
    </tbody>
  </table>
</script>
```

Controllers:

```
App.GradebookController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  getGrade: function(student, assignment) {
    console.log(arguments);
  }
});
```

Now, everything works fine and dandy except for the call to `getGrade`. The output of arguments shows that `student` and `assignment` are being passed as the literal string `"student"` and `"assignment"`. The regular output of `{{student}}{{assignment}}` is there for debugging and outputs something like `<App.Student:ember459:1><App.Assignment:ember453:1>` so I know that they are objects.

How can I get the `Student` and `Assignment` object from the `getGrade` call?

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I'm not even sure how you're getting the `getGrade` method to be called. I don't think that's valid Hanldebars syntax. To do what you want, you're going to have to write a Handlebars helper as detailed in the Ember.js guide [here](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/writing-helpers/).